# C# conditional multiple type checking with one out variable

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

i bet somewhere down the internet there has to be some answer to this but i havent found it in the last 30 minutes and i am not sure how to ask the question correctly.

i want to compare some input to multiple object types and put it inside the same variable not matter which object it is.

`if(input is typeOne || input is typeTwo)`

In C# you can initialize a variable inside an if statement like this:

```
if(input is typeOne inputeTypeOne){
  //i can use inputTypeOne here now
}
```

Is there a possibility to do something like the following:

```
if(input is typeOne OR typeTwo inputType){
  // use inputType no matter if typeOne or typeTwo
}
```

Comment: if `typeOne` and `typeTwo` have common interface then why formally they are not implements this interface ? so you could use `if(input is CommonInterface inputeType)`

Comment: what do `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo` have in common? If the answer is "nothing", then you cant put them in the same variable (well, not in any useful way anyway).

Comment: @Jamiec well.. i suppose you could put them in an `object` ;)

Comment: @CaiusJard at which point you can do nothing useful with it (hence the part in brackets)

Comment: @Jamiec There are exceptions to that, but I would expect you to know the answer already if you know how to use `object` already.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kind of proxy interface that will be common between the two classes:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
internal class Program
{
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TypeOne one = new TypeOne();
            TypeTwo two = new TypeTwo();
            var t = one.GetType();
            if (one is IProxyInterface)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Use me");
            }
        }
    }
    internal class TypeOne : IProxyInterface
    { }
    internal class TypeTwo : IProxyInterface
    { }
    public interface IProxyInterface { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not posible.
As C# is type safe.
Consider the following example.

```
if(input is string OR int inputType)
{ 
   
}
```

What is the type of `inputType`?
Could i use the `Contains` function on `inputType`?
If it was a `string` than it would be possible but if it was an `int` it should give a compile error.
To only way to do this is check for an common interface/parent.
Like so:

```
if (input is IParrent parrent)
{        
}

internal class TypeOne : IParrent
{ }

internal class TypeTwo : IParrent
{ }

public interface IParrent{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to do something like the following:

> ```
>    if(input is typeOne OR typeTwo inputType){
>       // use inputType no matter if typeOne or typeTwo
>    }
> ```

Yes, but only if typeOne or typeTwo derive from the same parent or implement the same interface

```
class Triangle: Shape ...
class Square: Shape ...
class Circle: Shape ...

if(someObject is Shape s)
   ...
```

But it's important to note that you can only treat the shapes as their common parent `s`. You can't go and access some property that is specific to triangle unless you know that the instance inside `s` is a triangle

```
var someObject = new Square();
if(someObject is Shape s) //yes
  Console.WriteLine("IsScalene: "+ s.IsScalene); //no
```

Not even if you cast it; just because it's a shape, doesn't mean it's a triangle

```
  Console.WriteLine("IsScalene: "+ (s as Triangle).IsScalene); //no
```

You'll need to ensure that whatever your code in your IF block wants to do with `s`, that it's using stuff that is available on Shape, or that it inpects and casts to a Square/Triangle appropriately before it does it

```
if(someObject is Shape s) //yes

  Console.Write(s.NumberOfSides); //all shapes have a number of sides; the property is defined at Shape level
  ...
  if(s is Triangle t) //it isn't a triangle
    ...
  else if(s is Square q)
    ...
```